# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes to a vectorized function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm making a python program in Google Colab, in this Colab I want to create a function that sends two Numpy arrays, one panda Dataframe and a string to a Numpy vectorized function. When I execute this piece of code I get the following error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6501398,) (6501398,) (462650,11) ()`.

Here is the code that I use:

```py
def calc_gem_bouwjaar(postcode_van_ascii, postcode_tot_ascii, BAG_grouped, foo_string):
    if (postcode_van_ascii != postcode_tot_ascii):
    total = 0
    amount = 0
    postcode_van_ascii = add_to_barcode(val=postcode_van_ascii, pos=1) # this just increments the value by one, and handles overflows in postal code format.

    while postcode_van_ascii != postcode_tot_ascii:
      try:
        # at is de snelste manier om data uit de dataframe te halen https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6683#issuecomment-38305770. 
        # df.ix lijkt nog sneller maar is sinds 0.23.4 deprecated https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html
        total += round(BAG_grouped.at[postcode_van_ascii, foo_string])
        amount += 1
      except:
        pass

      postcode_van_ascii = add_to_barcode(val=postcode_van_ascii, pos=1) # this just increments the value by one, and handles overflows in postal code format.

    try:
      return round(total/amount)
    except:
      # Error in division, probably no excisting data in grouped dataframe
      return 0

  else:
    try:
      return int(round(BAG_grouped.at[postcode_van_ascii, foo_string]))
    except:
      return 0


def foo(foo_string):
    # do other stuff
    BAG_grouped = BAG_df.groupby('postcode_ascii').mean()
    vconvert = np.vectorize(calc_gem_bouwjaar)

    postcode_van_array = np.asarray(Netbeheerders_df["POSTCODE_VAN_ASCII"]).astype(int)
    postcode_tot_array = np.asarray(Netbeheerders_df["POSTCODE_TOT_ASCII"]).astype(int)

    # foo_string = 'bouwjaar'
    result = vconvert(postcode_van_array, postcode_tot_array, BAG_grouped, foo_string).astype(int)  #<--- ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6501398,) (6501398,) (462650,11) ()


foo('bouwjaar')
```

Why does my code generate this error, and how may I solve this issue?

Comment: Why are you using `np.vectorize` if you haven't read its docs, or a basic numpy intro?

Comment: From `vectorize` docs:"The vectorized function evaluates `pyfunc` over successive tuples
of the input arrays like the python map function, except it uses the
**broadcasting rules of numpy**." (my emphasis added)  If you don't understand `numpy` broadcasting, don't use `vectorize`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `calc_gem_bouwjaar` does operations on your vectors via broadcasting. Since your vector shapes are not broadcastable (specifically `(6501398,)` `(462650,11)`,and  `()`), it throws the error. You have to look into your function and see where you are trying to do operations in need of broadcasting and fix corresponding shapes/operations. Without the content of the function, there is not much that we can add.

Comment: Hello Ehsan, thank you for your message. I have added the full function of  `calc_gem_bouwjaar`. My knowledge of python is not the best yet so I no clue what you mean with broadcasting. I have asked my uni group but they don't know it either. Can you give me some information and resources?

Comment: Hi, I have a hard time following your code as I do not know your functions/variables. Is there a reason why you prefer to use np.vectorzie? would a function not satisfy your purpose?